# TypeError raised when creating new-styled classes

Tags: python

I created a class that inherits from a proc class in runtime:

**proc.py**

```
class dummy_proc_class(object):
    def __init__(self, sp_id, group_id):
        self._sp_id = sp_id
        self._group_id = group_id
        self._processed = True

    @property
    def sp_id(self):
        return self._sp_id

    @property
    def processed(self):
        return self._processed

    def main(self):
        pass
```

**child.py**

```
class dynamic_child(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, *args, **kwargs):
        super(dynamic_child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._p1 = p1
        self._p2 = p2
        
    
    def main(self):
        msg1 = "My sp_id is: {}".format(self.sp_id)
        msg2 = "processed: {}".format(self.processed)
        print(msg1)
        print(msg2)
```

**main.py**

```
from proc import dummy_proc_class
from child import dynamic_child


dynamic_child = type('dynamic_child', (dummy_proc_class, object), dynamic_child.__dict__.copy())
child = dynamic_child(p1=1, p2=2, sp_id=123, group_id=456)
print(child.sp_id)
# My sp_id is: 123
# processed: True
```

However it raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/../dyn_inheritance/main.py", line 98, in <module>
    child = dynamic_child(p1=1, p2=2, sp_id=123, group_id=456)
  File "/home/../dyn_inheritance/child.py", line 5, in __init__
    super(dynamic_child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I was doing some research about it and seems that it's something related to `reload` modules, because if all these classes are in the same module it works.

I was playing around with `imp` library to reload the module when it changes but didn't work.
Is there a solution for this? or maybe another alternative to inherit in runtime

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why are you trying to define one class that uses the internals of a second class that has a hard-coded reference to the second class inside it?

Comment: @chepner The context is the following, the `dynamic_child` class needs to inherit from a class that uses a `process` library to execute tasks in background, the problem is that `dynamic_child` is a class that will be installed from a wheel package (python 2 & 3 compatible) but since we don't have a reference of the `dummy_proc_class` class yet, we need to find a way to make the child class inherits from proc class in runtime once the package is installed

Comment: I tested this putting all classes in the same module and worked, this is what we need .. inherit from that class in runtime

Comment: @maudev: Are you sure this works, as written, when it's all in the same module? Seems like it would only work if what you call `dynamic_child_proc` in `main.py` was renamed to `dynamic_child` in the combined code. You could conceivably (and terribly) make this work by adding `import child`, `child.dynamic_child = dynamic_child_proc` to `main.py` immediately after defining `dynamic_child_proc`, but ugh, this code smell stinks to high heaven.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, sorry I was trying multiple things and forget to rename the child class name. it's updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is fundamentally a scoping issue. The methods defined in `child.py` are bound at definition time such that they see the global scope of `child`, not `main`, so redefining `dynamic_child` in `main` doesn't change `child.dynamic_child` (which is what gets loaded and passed to the `super` call).

As a terrible, terrible hack, you could change the code in `main` to reach back into `child` and replace the `dynamic_child` defined there with your new `dynamic_child`, e.g.:

```
from proc import dummy_proc_class
import child

# Replace child's dynamic_child and also define local alias while you're at it
child.dynamic_child = dynamic_child = type('dynamic_child', (dummy_proc_class, object), child.dynamic_child.__dict__.copy())

child = dynamic_child(p1=1, p2=2, sp_id=123, group_id=456)
print(child.sp_id)
```

I wouldn't recommend this, since it's a terrible hack, but it should make your code work.

A more invasive method would be to make `child` provide a `dynamic_child_maker` function, rather than the raw class itself. It can take a base class to use, and avoid the hacky reconstruction of a class, e.g.:

```
def dynamic_child_maker(parent):
    class dynamic_child(parent, object):
        def __init__(self, p1, p2, *args, **kwargs):
            super(dynamic_child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self._p1 = p1
            self._p2 = p2
            
        
        def main(self):
            msg1 = "My sp_id is: {}".format(self.sp_id)
            msg2 = "processed: {}".format(self.processed)
            print(msg1)
            print(msg2)

    return dynamic_child
```

leaving your usage in `main` as:

```
from proc import dummy_proc_class
from child import dynamic_child_maker

dynamic_child = dynamic_child_maker(dummy_proc_class)
child = dynamic_child(p1=1, p2=2, sp_id=123, group_id=456)
print(child.sp_id)
```

This works because the class methods are constructed directly, in the same scope that the class itself is defined in, with no hackery that ends up mixing scopes (the class is wholly defined in, and solely uses, closure scope from the `dynamic_child_maker` function call, plus the `child` module globals if applicable). It also means when you port to Python 3 (because Python 2 has been dead for 18 months!), you can just use no-arg `super()` and save complexity (the magic behind no-arg `super()` doesn't work if you try to copy methods from one class to another).

Comment: Thanks and yes, actually that's the old approach that we had before, but we are changing the approach since our linter gets mad with the rules for a def function (the class inside is pretty large).
We only have these two alternatives to inherit in runtime, I'm pretty new in python so I'm not sure if there is another way to make this work

Comment: @maudev: Having a function the builds the class once, correctly (and works if you need to make multiple classes with different parents), is a strictly better solution than the hackery required to make your `type`-based dynamic class creation work. If this is a necessary thing in your program, the solution is to silence an overly picky linter, because sometimes, style has to be sacrificed to correctness.

Comment: I suppose you might get away with defining all methods that don't need to use `super` or refer to the parent outside the `def` and assigning them to names inside the class definition to keep it short, but frankly, that's worse than defining them inline; you'd be making your code stylistically *worse* to satisfy the linter (that's supposed to be demanding *better* code). Don't let the metrics for good code get in the way of writing better code.

Comment: thanks for the advices, and yes that's my last option before giving up :)